# Use filters which were created with fdatool in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, filter, mixed-programming

I created some filters with fdatool in Matlab. Now I want to use this filters in a windows  aplication using c++.

I search some libraries to filter in c++, but these libraries has functions which implement filters like chebyshev,etc. But i want use my filters.

How can i do? i know export coefficients in some formats, but how can use this in c++.

Thansk

Comment: No... use filters created in matlab, in a c++ project

Comment: Filters are Matlab functions?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that enable you to call Matlab functions (filters in you case) inside C++:

1. Distribute MATLAB into independent shared library: check out this [blog](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/2012/04/matlabc-cmatlab.html) on how to do this (with detail steps and example).
2. Call MATLAB Engine directly: Refer to [another blog](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/2013/12/matlabc-mixed-programming-call-matlab.html) for more info.